# General solution to svg in different broswers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, svg

I have the following problem:

I am programming with mvc .NET . In my views I use some SVG along with the HTML5. 
The results are ( not surprisingly) displayed in different ways in different browsers.

I am working with IE 11, Firefox 25.0.1 and Chrome 31.

Because there a really big differences, I looked for solutions to match the results. 
But until now I did not find a general solution to this problem. Is there any?

For example I have an svg image, which should scale to match the window-width.
It does in Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't in IE.
I have some links in this image, those are only displayed in IE, but neither in Firefox or Chrome.

Do I need to find a specific solution for every of my problems, or did I miss something out?

EDIT:

Here is the code for my example:

```
 <svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 854 748" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <image x="0" y="0"  width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="~/Images/logo.gif"/>

    <a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
       <rect x="46.83%" y="0%" width="8.2%" height="4.5%" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.0"></rect> 
   </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hard to tell unless you provide examples.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll add some

Comment: The fill-opacity of the rect is 0 which makes it rather hard to tell where it is but it does work as a link even so in Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson the logo is a picture of flags, and the link should be on top of each one, therefore it should be invisible. For testing just set it to 1.0. in any case I am confused now, because the links are created, I can see them via the Firefox "Inspector", but they do not appear when i hover over the link... And does the scaling work correctly in your case?

Comment: Are you loading this as a static file or creating it programatically? You already said that scaling works in Firefox. I expect IE just gets it wrong.

Comment: I load it as a static file. Is there some way to get the scaling right in IE, too?